# VB6 - Invalid call or procedure (Runtime Error 5)

Tags: file, vb6, runtime

I'm currently working on my college project, and have hit an obstacle.

I'm not quite sure where I have gone wrong here, as this code worked in a previous project (all the variable names have been correctly updated and checked).

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Login()
Dim User As UserRecord 'Sets the type as the record
Dim UserChannel As Integer 'Channel for User file
Dim UserRecordPointer As Integer 'Sets the record pointer for the User file as a whole number
Dim FoundAtLeastOneRecord As Boolean 'Declares the finding of a record as a binary digit (True or False)

UserFile = App.Path + "\GMP_TSS_DATA\user_data.dat"
FoundAtLeastOneRecord = False
UserRecordPointer = 1
UserChannel = FreeFile
Open UserFile For Random As UserChannel Len = UserLength
Get UserChannel, UserRecordPointer, User
Do While Not EOF(UserChannel)
    If Trim(User.Username) = Trim(TxtOfficerInformationLoginUsername.Text) And Trim(User.Password) = Trim(TxtOfficerInformationLoginPassword.Text) Then
        FrmOfficerInformation.Show
        FrmMainMenu.Hide
        Unload Me
        FoundAtLeastOneRecord = True
    Else
        MsgBox "The username and password you entered do not match. Please try again.", vbInformation, "Incorrect username or password"
    End If
    UserRecordPointer = UserRecordPointer + 1
    Get UserChannel, UserRecordPointer, User
Loop
Close UserChannel
If FoundAtLeastOneRecord = False Then 'If no records could be found then a message box will appear informing the user that this is the case.
    MsgBox ("A user profile could not be found. Please back-up and then delete the 'GMP_TSS_DATA' folder and restart the software."), vbExclamation, "Critical Error!"
End If
End Sub
```

The user file is located in a folder called "GMP_TSS_DATA" which is created in the root directory that the application is run from.

The error I get after clicking the "Login" button is runtime error 5: Invalid call or procedure.

I'd appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: Try removing the open and close parenthesis from this line:  MsgBox ("A user profile could not be found. Please back-up and then delete the 'GMP_TSS_DATA' folder and restart the software."), vbExclamation, "Critical Error!"

Comment: If UserLength = 0 you'll get that error. Also If UserLength is a local variable, it isn't defined. If that is true add `Option Explicit` as the very first line of you form code. That tells the compiler to require variable declaration and it is just a good practice.

Comment: Thanks @jac. I put that in but spelled it wrong ("Option Expilcit"), just a typo, but I would never had noticed! Thanks!